# Java: Как вычесть из текущего системного времени n минут

Tags: java, test-automation

В одном из шагов автотеста, для проверки системного контроля, требуется ввести текущее время, но меньше на 5 минут . Если с вводом текущего системного времени у меня проблем нет, то как получить системное время, но на 5 минут меньше, я не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много способов. Помимо данного в первом ответе:

Date a = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 5 * 60 * 1000);

Умножаем 5(минут)*60(секунд)*1000(миллисекуд) - получаем ответ в милисекундах и вычитаем.
А вообще такой [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833399/changing-java-date-one-hour-back) уже задавался на англоязычном stackOverflow. Там правда задача была вернуть на час назад, но разницы нет. Там, кстати, еще больше способов)

Comment: Чтобы не перемножать все кучу раз, можно еще так: `Date a = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)); `.         То есть вы вычитаете минуты (5), перведенные в миллисекунду не посредством умножения, а посредством специальной функции. Но в таком случае нужно добавить небольшой импорт: `import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;`

Comment: И еще, кстати, расскажу о разнице  того, что предложил Sergey Gornostaev в своем ответе и я в моем. У Сергея результат будет выводиться в таком формате: `2020-08-01T21:51:14.957659200` (LocalDateTime), у меня в таком: `Sat Aug 01 21:51:14 MSK 2020` (BaseCalendar). Выбирайте, что вам удобнее. (Тестировал на своем времени)

Comment: Есть еще много способов. Все они - по данной мной ссылке

Comment: Алексей, если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, примите его поставив галочку. Это даст другим понять, что вопрос решен, а мне - несколько баллов опыта за полезный ответ.

Answer (score 6):

```
LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(5)
```